# Hiding footer in ListView

Tags: android, listview

When my Activity loads, I inflate a layout file that I use for a footer.  I attach it to the ListView (addFooterView) and then set its visibility to View.GONE.  I maintain a reference to it, and when I want the user to see it, I set the visibility to View.VISIBLE.

For the most part, this works great.  However, the footer seems to still take up space.  If the user uses the scroll wheel/pad, the area the footer is taking up gets highlighted.  I'd like to polish this more so the footer is completely gone; ideally without detaching it from the ListView.

Is this possible? Or am I going to have to set/unset the foot instead of simply toggling its visibility?

Comment: You cannot detach a footer from a ListView, AFAIK.

Comment: There is a method "removeFooterView(View v)" of ListView

Comment: Sorry, my apologies for missing that.

Comment: It's really quite useless as it only works if you use it before ListView.setAdapter, which you would usually do in the ListActivity's onCreate().

Comment: Which is probably why I had put it out of my mind... :-)

Comment: I've updated my answer with the list of steps. It's annoying, for sure but I use it to hide/show "loading" messages and "no results" messages too, it would suck if I had two empty views.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `listView.removeFooterView(view)`. The easiest way to do this is to create an instance variable to hold your inflated footer view (so you only inflate it in `onCreate()` ). Then just call `listView.addFooterView(instanceFooter)` and `listView.removeFooterView(instanceFooter)` as needed.

Edit:
Here's what I'm doing to get this to work:

1. inflate footer layout(s) in `onCreate`
2. onResume: **IF** the adapter has not been instantiated, call `addFooterView()` THEN initialize your adapter (keep an instance reference to it) and call `setAdapter()`. This will leave the `ListView` "prepped"
3. onResume: update the adapter with the data (I have my data in a separate class) and call `notifyDatasetChanged()`
4. Call `removeFooterView()` (it will hide it if it's being displayed and do nothing otherwise)
5. Call `addFooterView()` if the footer needs to be displayed

Comment: I don't think this works. If I remember correctly, you have to add the footer before setting the adapter for it to show up.

Comment: I've tested it out just now and my memory seems to be accurate.

Comment: This will work if I use mList.setAdapter(mAdapter); instead of mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();, but that seems kind of silly. It also messes up the ListView's scrolling.

Comment: Err, this totally works for me. But you're right in the sense that the footer has to be added first, though that is the rule for adding a footer anyway (which he is already successfully doing). But yes, the trick is adding it a the beginning regardless of whether you want to show it or not, then calling `removeFooter()`/`addFooter()` on demand. I'll update the answer with the steps of how I got it working.

Comment: This does work if you call addFooter() once before setting the adapter.

Comment: It's worked fine for me and my two footers. I can add/remove them without any issues.

Comment: I'm tried footer visible and gone but not achieve my goal but after see your answer I'm done it man. Nice answer with nice explanation @dmon

Answer (score 2):

You can toggle the visibility. To do that, you need to wrap the content of your footer using a linearlayout, then you set the linearlayout visibility to GONE.

In the example bellow I set the visibility of LogoLinearLayout to GONE and it worked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LogoLinearLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Logo"
                android:src="@drawable/Logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing3"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing3"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set isSelectable parameter to false when You call addFooterView to disable footer selection and highlighting

Answer (score -2):

Try using View.INVISIBLE instead of View.GONE. (I have not tried this,but it might work)

Comment: This doesn't work. It seemed like a longshot, but I tried it anyway to no avail.  I am essentially getting the result of View.INVISIBLE when setting the visibility to View.GONE.